# Javascript Audio - createAnalyser Select frequency range

Tags: javascript, audio

I am creating an audio visualiser in javascript, and I can't find a solution to limit the frequencies i am listening to, from 20Hz to 8K Hz. Here is the code sample :
Here is the initialisation function :

```
var _context = new AudioContext();
var _analyser = _context.createAnalyser();
_analyser.fftSize = 512;

var _frequencyData = new Uint8Array( _analyser.frequencyBinCount );
```

It's a bar graph representing frequencies gain. But I have nothing after half the graph given that my sound doesn't emit anything after 8k Hz ( i think ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you'd like to visualize an FFT but you don't want it to display any frequencies above 8kHz. There are 2 options:

1) You can try setting the sample rate to 16kHz which would give you 8kHz audio bandwidth. I'm not sure of browser support for this. Refer to https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/300 for more details.

2) Disregard any of the frequency bins beyond your desired frequency. The bin starting frequency can be found by multiplying the bin index by 1/2 the sample rate over the the total number of bins. For example, for a 512 point FFT at 48000:

```
bin 0:   0 * 48000.0/2/512 = 0 Hz
bin 511: 511 * 48000.0/2/512 = 23953.125 Hz
```

With a little algebra you can solve for the bin # containing any desired frequency:

```
startFreq = binNum * sr/2/numBins
```

therefore:

```
binNum = startFreq * numBins / (sr/2)

8000 * 512 / (48000/2) = 170.67
```

So 8kHz would be present in `_analyzer.getFloatFrequencyData()[170]` of the 512 point FFT at 48kHz.

You can determine the sample rate from `_context.sampleRate`

Comment: Are you sure about the bin 511 being 47kHz? I mean, Nyquist theorem should apply here so last bin is half the frequency?

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg. Geez I don't know what I was thinking. I updated my answer. Thanks.